# Parse Push Notification Include Users TimeZone in Push-Time

Tags: javascript, datetime, parse-platform, push-notification, timezone

Is it possible to include the users' timezone if I want to send a push notification containing a datetime?

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: query, // Set our Installation query
    data: {
        type: 2, // new applications push
        applicationID: applicationID,
        startTime: startTime,
        "alert" : {
            "title-loc-key": "SUCCESSFUL_TITLE",
            "loc-key": "SUCCESSFUL_MESSAGE",
            "loc-args": [startTime]
        },
        "sound": "default",
        "content-available" : "1",
        "badge" : 'Increment'
    }
```

So the push message displays a time like "[some text] at 01.02.2016, 19:00 Uhr". 
I hardcoded a timezone with moment.js in the cloudcode - but for the future, different users from different regions should get date and time information in their respective timezones... Is it possible to achieve this with the Parse.Push call and without manual iteration over the Installation table?

Comment: I updated your tags. [tag:parsing] is about interpreting strings.  You meant [tag:parse.com], relating to the Parse.com platform.  Still, it's unclear what you are asking.  Could you give a few more examples of what exactly you would like to see?  How did you incorporate moment.js?  What actually goes over the wire?

Comment: Thanks. We send push Notifications to Users With a cloudcode Function. This  Push Message contains a datetime. With future developments in mind this datetime is different according to the timezone the User is located at. Wie have to handle the sending process server side and thus sent specific datetimes from server side. My question was if Parse provides a default Function for adjusting users timezone in the message, or if I Need to create a Manual method that iterates over all installation objects and creates an individual push for each user (or using channels)

Comment: Does the user *see* the time within the message content?  if not, just convert to UTC for all users.

Comment: Yes thats the Point. The Message contains the Time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Parse.com documentation, there is an [`Installation`](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#push-notifications-installations) object in which you can get the user's time zone via the `timeZone` parameter.

> `timeZone`: The current time zone where the target device is located. This value is synchronized every time an Installation object is saved from the device.

Elsewhere in the documentation for their REST API, they talk about [local push scheduling](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications-local-push-scheduling), and describe the `Installation.timeZone` parameter in terms of IANA time zone IDs, such as `America/New_York` or `America/Los_Angeles`.  These IDs are the same ones that [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) uses.

So first you need to load [moment](http://momentjs.com/) and [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), along with some time zone data. Probably you want the `moment-timezone-2010-2020.js` file.

Then you can do something like this:

```
var timeZone = Installation.timeZone; // or however you get this from Parse.com

var startTime = '2015-09-27T12:00:00Z';  // ISO-8601 format

var m = moment(startTime).tz(timeZone);  // converted to the user's time zone
var s = m.calendar();  // or m.format, or whatever you want

var message = "Hi Bob, your event starts " + s;
```

Then push out the message as you showed in your question

Comment: Also, sorry but I'm not 100% familiar with Parse.com.  Perhaps someone else can elaborate or qualify this approach.  I'm not sure if `Installation.timeZone` is readily available, or if you have to use `Parse.Query` to get it.

Comment: this may be a solution but my question was if there's a possibility to incorporate the timeZone in the Parse.Push command automatically (see above)- so to say you just have to call Parse.Push(...) with a message string and a time in it (that appears in the push message) and parse automatically adjust this time to the users timezone. Your example is what would do if there's not such a possibility - creating a loop that sends individual pushes - but there's an execution limit this way. Thats the main point if this message goes out to thousand of recipients.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Well then I'll let someone with more experience on Parse.com respond on that point.  Sounds like you need some kind of templating approach.  Or perhaps group your messages by time zone and send a different message to the batch of users in each time zone.

Comment: You might also try asking on [the parse-developers Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers).

Comment: I followed your advise and posted this question also in the Google Group. Thank you so far Matt!